# Asp.net Routing not working properly

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have written the following inside my RegisterRoutes() in Global.asax in webforms application.
I have an xml file called CacheInfo.xml that stores the details of cached pages.The default page has an entry in the xml called EnDefaultPage, which contains two child nodes.
The child node LastUpdationTimeStamp stores, last updation timestamp (unix timestamp in seconds ) of the cache for Default page.

The child node ExpiryTimestamp stores the timestamp at which the cache will be expired.So if the expiry timestamp is greater than lastupdation timestamp, the file from Cache will be loaded (Default.html).Currently the script is working, but it is not routing to the Default.html although the conditional block that defines the route is being executed.I couldn't find the exact reason behind the issue.Can anybody suggest me a fix.All the other routes are working perfectly.
My code is attached below.

```
ublic void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        string relPath = "~/CacheInfo.xml";
        string absPath = Server.MapPath(relPath);


        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();//xml doc used for xml parsing

        xdoc.Load(
            absPath
            );//loading XML in xml doc

        string nodeName="", nodeVal="",upStamp="0",expiry="0";
        int iUpStamp,iExpiry;
        upStamp = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("EnDefaultPage")[0].SelectSingleNode("LastUpdationTimeStamp").InnerText;
        expiry =  xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("EnDefaultPage")[0].SelectSingleNode("ExpiryTimeStamp").InnerText;

        iUpStamp = Convert.ToInt32(upStamp);
        iExpiry = Convert.ToInt32(expiry);

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(upStamp)) {
            if (iExpiry > iUpStamp)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("stamp is " + upStamp + " Expiry is " + expiry);
                //  routes.MapPageRoute("EnHome1", "", "~/en/DefaultCache.aspx");
                routes.MapPageRoute("EHome", "en/", "~/en/Default.html");
               //this routing is not working
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        routes.MapPageRoute("GArticle", "Gallery/{slug}", "~/Gallery/Article.aspx");


        routes.MapPageRoute("GCategory", "Gallery/Categories/{slug}", "~/Gallery/Categories.aspx");

        routes.MapPageRoute("GSlideShow", "Gallery/{slug}/{id}", "~/Gallery/SlideShow.aspx");

        routes.MapPageRoute("Article", "en/{slug}", "~/english/Article.aspx");


        routes.MapPageRoute("Category", "en/Categories/{slug}", "~/english/Categories.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("enFeed", "en/category/english/{slug}/feed", "~/en/feed.aspx");

        routes.MapPageRoute("teFeed", "te/category/telugu/{slug}/feed", "~/te/feed.aspx");

         routes.MapPageRoute("Tags", "en/Tags/{tag}", "~/english/Tags.aspx");



         routes.MapPageRoute("tArticleHtml", "te/{slug}.html", "~/telugu/Article.aspx");

         routes.MapPageRoute("tArticle", "te/{slug}", "~/telugu/Article.aspx");


         routes.MapPageRoute("tCategoryHtml", "te/Categories/{slug}.html", "~/telugu/Categories.aspx");
         routes.MapPageRoute("tCategory", "te/Categories/{slug}", "~/telugu/Categories.aspx");

         routes.MapPageRoute("tTagsHtml", "te/Tags/{tag}.html", "~/telugu/Tags.aspx"); 

         routes.MapPageRoute("tTags", "te/Tags/{tag}", "~/telugu/Tags.aspx");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read your intent correctly, you want the user to be directed to default any time their access is expired. If so, you can't get there from here.

RegisterRoutes is used to register routes as the application starts up.The last 3 words are the clue as to why certain logic will not work later in the application.

Now to your RegisterRoutes. Here is the logic.

1. Get expiration date
2. Get timestamp
3. If the expiration date is greater than last updated, when the application starts, route the user to default

If you truly mean "at startup determine whether to route every page that can be expired to default, every time" then you have the correct logic and it is working as expected. The fact you asked the question says that is not your intent. You want a decision made on a page access by page access basis. If I am correct, you can't do it in RegisterRoutes. You will have to implement the "caching logic" elsewhere.

My suggestion, rather than building this by hand, is look into software that handles caching.

Comment: Thanks ...But what is the reason behind   routes.MapPageRoute("EHome", "en/", "~/en/Default.html"); not working?Any solution

Comment: Is this your intent? 1. Start up web server 2. Determine if all currently expired pages (at startup) go to default.htm. If you want it on a case by case basis (is it expired now, not on application start), then you can't do it this way. RegisterRoutes is designed to set up a "dictionary" of routes, so to speak, at START UP. It is not used for runtime conditional logic. More than likely, it is working perfectly, from the start up perspective, but you want runtime determination. If you do, I would suggest looking at something like the OutputCache, which is not used in RegsiterRoutes.

Comment: NOTE: If you need custom caching, you still cannot implement it for runtime in RegisterRoutes.